How to fix INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR while flask backend deploying on vercel?
everyone!
Could you help me?
I've successfully deployed the flask backend locally using vercel dev, but it still doesn't work with vercel.
Error:
This Serverless Function has crashed.
Your connection is working correctly.
Vercel is working correctly.
500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Thank you.

I would be hard to guess the problem without server-side logs and probably crashing function code. Please, look for the error with full stack trace in logs.
